# QT C++ forward-declaration problem?

Tags: c++, qt, qt4, cmake, forward-declaration

I am trying to use QTPropertyBrowser to edit properties in my QObjects.
From QT Solutions "QtPropertyBrowser" example I use following files in my project.

http://qt.gitorious.org/qt-solutions/qt-solutions/blobs/master/qtpropertybrowser/examples/object_controller/objectcontroller.cpp

http://qt.gitorious.org/qt-solutions/qt-solutions/blobs/master/qtpropertybrowser/examples/object_controller/objectcontroller.h

I configure my CMakeFile as follows :

```
#include_directories("/usr/include")
SET(QTVIEW_SRCS 
  src/main.cpp  
  src/TestWidget.cpp
  src/plugin/IPlugin.cpp
  src/objectcontroller.cpp
)

SET(QTVIEW_MOH_HDRS
 src/TestWidget.h
 src/plugin/IPlugin.h
 src/objectcontroller.h

)
```

When I compile the files as they are, compiler giving error as follows -

> C:\svn\osaka3d\trunk\osaka3d\QTView\src\moc_objectcontroller.cxx:
>   In member function 'virtual int
>   ObjectController::qt_metacall(QMetaObject::Call,
>   int, void**)' :
>   C:\svn\osaka3d\trunk\osaka3d\QTView\src\moc_objectcontroller.cxx:73:
>   error: invalid use of incomplete type
>   'struct ObjectControllerPrivate'
>   C:\svn\osaka3d\trunk\osaka3d\QTView\src/objectcontroller.h:45:
>   error: forward declaration of 'struct
>   ObjectControllerPrivate'
>   C:\svn\osaka3d\trunk\osaka3d\QTView\src\moc_objectcontroller.cxx:73:
>   error: expected type-specifier before
>   'QtProperty'
>   C:\svn\osaka3d\trunk\osaka3d\QTView\src\moc_objectcontroller.cxx:73:
>   error: expected '>' before
>   'QtProperty'
>   C:\svn\osaka3d\trunk\osaka3d\QTView\src\moc_objectcontroller.cxx:73:
>   error: expected '(' before
>   'QtProperty'
>   C:\svn\osaka3d\trunk\osaka3d\QTView\src\moc_objectcontroller.cxx:73:
>   error: 'QtProperty' was not declared
>   in this scope
>   C:\svn\osaka3d\trunk\osaka3d\QTView\src\moc_objectcontroller.cxx:73:
>   error: expected primary-expression
>   before ')' token mingw32-make[2](http://qt.gitorious.org/qt-solutions/qt-solutions/blobs/master/qtpropertybrowser/examples/object_controller/objectcontroller.h): ***
>   [CMakeFiles/qtview.dir/src/moc_objectcontroller.cxx.obj]
>   Error 1 mingw32-make[1](http://qt.gitorious.org/qt-solutions/qt-solutions/blobs/master/qtpropertybrowser/examples/object_controller/objectcontroller.cpp):** 
>   [CMakeFiles/qtview.dir/all] Error 2
>   mingw32-make: ** [all] Error 2

**But when I comment out the line :**

```
Q_PRIVATE_SLOT(d_func(), void slotValueChanged(QtProperty *, const QVariant &))
```

in "objectcontroller.h"

**and comment out the line :**

```
#include "moc_objectcontroller.cxx"
```

and the end of file "objectcontroller.cpp" , it compiles well But i cannot use SIGNALS/SLOTs to reflect editing of QObject parameters.

Any tips?

Answer (score 6):

I ran into the same problem (I am new to qt, but this worked for me). For other people searching a solution I found this:

### What is happening

The issue is that due to `Q_PRIVATE_SLOT` macro the generated `moc_XXX.cxx` needs the full declaration of the `XXXPrivate` class to call the private slot function. As the public header only forward declares it, the generated cxx can not be compiled on its own. The *QtPropertyBrowser* guys circumvented this problem by including the generated `moc_XXX.cpp` (mind the 'pp', cmake generates 'xx')) in their source file (ugly, but works). I also do not know any other way to tell the *moc* to include (the in this case even not present) private `XXX_p.hpp`. So let's stick to that way.

What I did next was to remove the generated `moc_XXX.cxx` files from the executable, but this resulted in the *moc* never being called. This happened even though I used `QT4_WRAP_CPP`. So after further searching I found...

One addendum to this special case: the `QtProperty` declaration is missing. Either add the following forward declaration or the appropriate include file:

```
#if QT_VERSION >= 0x040400
QT_BEGIN_NAMESPACE
#endif

class QtProperty;

#if QT_VERSION >= 0x040400
QT_END_NAMESPACE
#endif
```

### Solution

Full credit goes to *fullmetalcoder* who presented this cmake function:

```
function(qt4_wrap_hdrs _moc_srcs)
  qt4_get_moc_flags(_moc_incs)
  set(_mocs)
  foreach(_current_file ${ARGN})
    get_filename_component(_abs_file ${_current_file} ABSOLUTE)
    if(EXISTS ${_abs_file})
      file(READ ${_abs_file} _contents)
      get_filename_component(_basename ${_abs_file} NAME_WE)
      string(REGEX MATCH "Q_OBJECT" _match "${_contents}")
      if(_match)
        set(_moc "${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/moc_${_basename}.cpp")
        qt4_create_moc_command(${_abs_file} ${_moc} "${_moc_incs}" "")
        macro_add_file_dependencies(${_abs_file} ${_moc})
        list(APPEND _mocs ${_moc})
      endif(_match)
    endif(EXISTS ${_abs_file})
  endforeach (_current_file)
  set(${_moc_srcs} ${_mocs} PARENT_SCOPE)
endfunction(qt4_wrap_hdrs)
```

(from http://www.qtcentre.org/threads/37428-using-QT-unit-testing-with-CMake)

You can use this function as a drop-in replacement for `QT4_WRAP_CPP`. You now only need to add the following line into your CMakeLists.txt so that the compiler finds the generated `moc_XXX.cpp` files (the new function created a 'pp' file...):

```
include_directories(${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR})
```

This function calls the *moc* all the time and behaves more like as in the *qmake* case. Except of course that you can easily do out of source builds.

But there is one caveat: all `moc_XXX.cpp` files are generated in the `CMAKE_BINARY_DIR`. So if you have two files `include1/foo.hpp` and `include2/foo.hpp` one will be overwritten!

Answer (score 1):

Have you read the following article about using Qt and CMake together?

http://developer.qt.nokia.com/quarterly/view/using_cmake_to_build_qt_projects

Maybe you're forgetting something, like calling `QT4_WRAP_CPP` on your CMakeLists.txt.

Comment: This link is no longer valid.